# cannot login when username and password are correct

Tags: php, authentication, registration

Hello so I am doing this tutorial from php academy for a php and mysql login and registration form. It was going okay.. he was showing how to idk what the correct way to say it but to create functions to echo errors.. yeah that sounds right. So the first couple errors echoed correctly but the one to actually validate the user_id and whatknot, isn't working. Its showing the error I created when the username and password combination is incorrect even when i submit the correct information. I've created a few dummy users and none of them can get through.

this is my code..

```
include 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
$errors[] = 'Uh oh! You forgot to enter your username and password';

} else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
$errors[] = 'Who is that? Have you registered?';

} else if (user_active($username) === false) {
$errors[] = 'Account is not activated.';

} else {

$login = login($username, $password);
if ($login === false) {
$errors[] = 'That username and password combination is incorrect';

} else {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
    header('Location:index.php');
    exit();
    }
}
print_r($errors);
}

include 'includes/overall/footer.php';
```

and

```
function logged_in() {
return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
}

function user_exists($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}


function user_active($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` = 1");
return  (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_id_from_username($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id');
}

function login($username, $password) {
$user_id = user_id_from_username($username);

$username = sanitize($username);
$password = md5($password);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");
return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}
```

does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I've tried a few things and nothing works. For example in the video he does it a little different and puts his queries in line but that was giving me errors so i did it the way he originally had it and made the queries variables (i only have somewhat of an idea what I'm actually saying haha).. but that fixed the errors. I tried doing that to the other functions (not shown) but that caused a whole lot of errors :(

is it something really dumb? I had a similar problem before that I figured out was due to a missing semi colon but I've stared at this stupid code for so long and haven't found anything.. I re-watched the videos in the tutorial series that explain all this like 10 times each.. my eyes feel like they are going to bleed or explode. Some of the comments show that others are having similar issues..  help?

I'm new to all this php mysql stuff so.. I wont be offended if u speak to me like a child.. in fact its appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated, use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: On another note, I believe OWASP discouraged telling whether or not a username existed, and instead proposed the vague "username or password incorrect". you could remove your `user_exists` function, save a database query, and increase security.

Comment: @jeni are the passwords in the database MD5 correctly encrypted ?
Otherwise do you get a parse error ?

Comment: so I have no previous knowledge of php really .. this is for practice because i heard you should just screw the books and stuff and dive right in... that being said.. almost everything you guys are saying is going right over my head.. :/ but @HamZaDzCyberDev - yes I believe the passwords are encrypted correctly. at least they are encrypted in my table in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @arxanas.. why would they tell me to use deprecated code? :/ and if i remove the function.. wouldn't it still be broken but I just won't get the message?

Comment: @jeni They told you "deprecated code" because it's an "old" tutorial, The Computer World advances and so PHP, i once programmed a website and after about 1 year i got some deprecating messages i was like :O.
Althought it's not a really bad idea for the moment to learn with mysql_*, but at the end you should get over to PDO/mysqli !

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that you are unable to login now?

I had similar problems in the past. I do not see your mistake but I will share a method that allowed me to find mistakes.

1. Store the MySQL query in a variable as a string and data inputted from a form
2. echo that variable
3. Test the outputted string in phpMyAdmin - if the query is wrong it will give you a hint what is wrong with it.

Also it might be worth testing the queries with "LIKE" instead of "="

eg.

```
.....FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '$username'.....
```

Comment: yeah I can't log in at all. I don't really know how to do what you're suggesting.. it probably isn't but it sounds complicated. I'm going to try that LIKE thing though. thx

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
function user_exists($username) {
  $username = sanitize($username); 
  return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' "),0) ==1) ? true : false; 
}
```